# Error (http status 500) when i use Spring with tiles

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, tiles, apache-tiles

I created a project spring + tiles but I always get this error.I have read many guides but can not seem to solve the problem. Where am I doing wrong?Thanks

[image]

tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="template" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/classic.jsp">
<put-attribute name="title" value="Tiles tutorial homepage" />
<put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/banner.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/common_menu.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/home_body.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/credits.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="home" extends="template">
<put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp"/>
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVCTiles</display-name>

<servlet>
 <servlet-name>hellotiles</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 </servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>hellotiles</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

hellotiles-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="coreservlets"/>

 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer" >
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list> 
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

HelloController.java

```
package coreservlets;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value="/hello",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String stampaHello(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("messaggio","Ciao scusate il ritardo");
    return "hello";
}//stampaHello

@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String visualizzaIndex(){
    return "index";
}//visualizzaIndex

}//HelloController
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${messaggio}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="/SpringMVCTiles/hello">Stampa ciao</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What `ViewResolver` should handle the `index` name?. It has not been defined on tiles.. so has sense the error.

Comment: Thanks , I replaced name="home" with name="index" in tiles.xml and and I solved the problem

Comment: I am going to share it how a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `ViewResolver` should handle the `index` name?. It has not been defined on **tiles.xml**. so has sense the error

Your `@Controller` return two *view names*, they are *hello* and *index*, but your **tiles.xml** definition has only one and it is **home**